# Are there some common problems with making an app iOS 5 compatible?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, upgrade, ios5

I'm testing my app with the iOS 5 beta and have run across several problems. Some content in my table views doesn't show up correctly and a segmentcontrol with up/down arrows in the navBar won't display.

I started thinking that I might not be the first person to encounter these problems and it would really help if we share the problems and solutions we're encountering while we make our apps iOS 5 ready.

Comment: Isn't there still an NDA issue with iOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of APIs were changed in iOS 5, so you probably aren't the only one. However, this is still under NDA so I won't mention anything else here. If you'd like help please ask someone in the Apple Developer Forums. http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

gonna have to use the [apple developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com/) for this one for a while.